# Como combinar dos columnas en Power Query

Tags: excel, powerbi

No se si lo correcto sea combinar las columnas pero tengo el siguiente problema que me gustaría resolver con ustedes y me puedan dar una mejor orientación y es lo siguiente:

Tengo dos hojas de excel las cuales las estoy usando como origen de datos para un reporte en Power BI, una de estas hojas esta con los siguientes datos:

**HOJA 1:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y la otra hoja de excel con estos datos:

**HOJA 2:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En un mismo reporte quiero representar la información de las dos hojas, como bien saben en Power BI cada hoja de excel la representa como una tabla, pero al momento de agregar el filtro de `Location` de la hoja 1 no me trae los valores de `Area C`, entiendo que es porque estoy filtrando por la columna `Location` de la hoja 1.

Lo que quiero hacer es tener una columna `Location` global como filtro donde se encuentren los valores `Area A, Area B, Area C`, y al momento de ejecutar el filtro se apliquen dinamicamente a los datos que se encuentran en la hoja 1 y hoja 2.

No le veo sentido a tener dos filtros de Location con la única diferencia de que uno tiene mas valores que otro.

No se si lo correcto sea combinar las dos columnas o hacer una relación de varios a varios, espero que me puedan orientar a tomar la mejor decisión.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aunque Power BI permite trabajar de diferentes formas y para modelos sencillos parezca que todo vale, existen unos fundamentos básicos y unas buenas prácticas a seguir.

En lo básico esto significa que debemos tener en cuenta unos conceptos: deben existir tablas de hechos (las que contienen datos) y tablas de dimensiones. Estas tablas deben tener una relación en estrella.

En tu caso significa que tienes dos tablas de hechos (Hoja 1 y Hoja 2) y 3 dimensiones (Items, locations, Services). Deberías por tanto tener cargado en Power BI estas 5 tablas. Las tablas de dimensiones las puedes construir fácilmente con Power Query.

Cada columna de la tabla de hechos (las que no tienen datos a sumar, contar, etc) debe tener una relación de 1 a N con su correspondiente dimensión. Los campos de las tablas de hechos no se utilizan jamás, si necesitas un filtro debe salir de una tabla de dimensión.

Por otro lado debes crear medidas, no es necesario en modelos pequeños, pero si en modelos medianos y grandes si quieres que sea eficiente. En tu caso tienes dos medidas: Quantity y Price, las construyes del siguiente modo:

```
Price = SUM('Hoja 1'[Price])
Quantity = SUM('Hoja 2'[Quantity])
```

Por otro lado, también puedes reducir el número de tablas de hechos y quedarte con una sola. Como bien dices puedes unir las dos tablas con la opción de Power Query de "Combinar consultas". Simplemente le dices qué columnas tienen en común.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Excelente respuesta, clara y concisa